# Reversing the order of items on a Google Sheet populated by a Google Form

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Form that populates to a Google Sheet. I want the new entries to appear at the top instead of the bottom...is there a script to do this?  I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: You can't change the way Google populates a sheet with answers. However, you should be able to just sort the sheet when viewing it.

Answer (score 2):

You might try (I haven't) working from a *copy* of your form results (say they are in `Form responses 1` and span the first 26 columns):

```
=query('Form responses 1'!A:Z,"order by A desc")
```

in A1 of a new sheet.